# From where to launch AlarmManager?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask, alarmmanager

I try to make an application to periodically report to a server, and I want this start since the application is installed. My question is from where do I launch the AlarmManager?

Comment: Report to a server whilst your app is open or at any time even if your app has not been started?

Comment: At all times, even with the closed application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the alarm as soon as your application starts, you can do it in your `Application` class. For that create a class let's say `MyApplication` which extends `Application` class  and in its `onCreate()` method, set your alarm. `onCreate()` will invoke as soon as you launch a new instance of your application.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      //Set Alarm here
   }
}
```

And to tell Android runtime that `MyApplication` is your application class, change your application's manifest file :

```
<application
        android:name="<your_package_name>.MyApplication"
....
>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Does the onCreate () method when running? After installing the application or to activate the application?

Comment: onCreate () is called as soon as you launch the application  for the first time and/or  whenever you relaunch it after it is killed.

Comment: When is it considered that the application is killed? I would like the task of sending data, the application can not be killed.

Comment: The app can be killed due to several reasons e.g. when you remove it from the recent apps list, when you force stop it , when your app is in background and other foreground apps need memory, then Android runs GC and kills your app so that foreground active apps get memory in case they are short of.

Comment: I have found that your idea works. Although I am now struggling with another problem, I give an interval of 1 minute AlarmManager, but this delay as 5 minutes to respond. Can you imagine what could be the problem?

Comment: Please raise a new question for this as it is no more related with the question you asked here. Also, please support your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) listening for the

> android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

intent.

Use the broadcast receiver `onReceive` method to set up your alarms.

Note that this requires

> android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but it is not the solution. This is released every time the device is turned on. My intention is to raise the alarm since the application is installed.

Comment: your code is blocked from running by the Android system until the user has specifically started your app for the first time. You would start your alarms in the app for the first time but as alarms are  removed every time the device reboots, yo would use the method in my answer to set them up again.